# python regex to extract username:password or email:password in mixed delimited csv

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have (thousands of) csv files containing an assortment of (billions of) rows such as:

combos.csv

```
example0@domain.tld:passw0rd
ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld;p@££w0r46&
0-0-0 ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld p@££w0r46&
ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld:00-00-00;p@££w0r46& <-- updated line
00-00-00:username:password
username:p@££w0r46&
username p@££w0r46&
and more...
```

I am trying to extract email or username and password for some machine learning assignment I am doing. But I cannot seem to nail down the correct regex for this.

using `re.split`, `re.findall` or `re.search` seems to be the options here, and I'm trying to compile a regex that will allow me to simply print e.g.:

```
Email: "example0@domain.tld" Password: "passw0rd"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Username: "username" Password: "password"
Username: "username" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Username: "username" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
```

From the above `combos.csv`

I've managed to use the following for email/password combo:

```
re.compile(r'(?:.*[:|;])?(?P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)[:|;](?P<Password>.*)')
```

but extracting username/password I haven't managed yet. I've tried with look-behind on ; and : but it seems that when the row is delimited twice, my current regex will return the first column as username and the two next as password:

```
re.compile(r'^(?:.*[:|;])?(?P<username>[A-z0-9\.\-\_\$\#\&]+)(?!@)[:|;](?P<password>.*)')
```

How can I do this properly, and better yet, is there a solution where one regex can do everything?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Try `re.search(r'(?P<username>[^;: ]+)[:; ](?P<password>[^;: ]+)$', line).groupdict()` when reading the file line by line.

Comment: This discards the first column in all situations. I'll try this and see if I can work it, thanks! If you have a full solution, I'd be more than happy to checkmark the answer.

Comment: You have not specified toy need anything before that. Add `^(?P<start>.*?)` at the beginning if you need that data. If you need no separator, use `re.search(r'^(?:(?P<start>.*?)[:; ])?(?P<username>[^;: ]+)[:; ](?P<password>[^;: ]+)$', line).groupdict()`, see https://ideone.com/PCkmHQ

Comment: I apologize, I've update my answer a bit.

Comment: Ok, so do you want to keep any data except username and password or not? If not, just use two regexps to extract the email-like pattern (like yours) and then any 1+ chars other than field delimiter chars at the end of each line.

Comment: I only want email/password or username/password, hopefully in one regex test (as opposed to testing for either). Because of the amount of lines, testing each line potentially two times will exponentially increase the time it will take.

Comment: I doubt that is an issue, it will take a lot more time if you use a pattern like `(email).*?(pass)|(pass).*?(email)` and then figuring out where is what data.

Comment: You've got a point. I think I will use `r'(?P<identifier>[^;: ]+)[:; ](?P<password>[^;: ]+)$'` as you first suggested, and just dump the rest to a series of pickles for later consumption. Thanks

Comment: I can't understand how you want to match the `Username` and differentiate it from an email.

Comment: Please see https://ideone.com/WXirln, does it do what you mean to get?

Comment: I can work with your last suggestion, I just need to account for filesize and time here. ~1ms is far to much time per line

Comment: Good, I posted a [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518429/3832970). Even if it is not the solution you want it looks helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to extract email, password and optional username data from each line you may use

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'[:; ]')
rx_email = re.compile(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+$')
with open(your_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = rx.split(line)
        email = ''
        id = ''
        for field in fields:
            if rx_email.match(field):
                email = field
            elif field != fields[-1]:
                id = field
        password = fields[-1]
        print("Username: '{}', email: '{}', password: '{}'".format(id, email, password))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/WXirln).

The `^\S+@\S+\.\S+$` pattern matches email-like fields, that start with 1+ non-whitespace chars, then have `@`, again 1+ non-whitespace chars, `. and end with 1+ non-whitespace chars.

The `[:; ]` pattern used with `re.split` splits with space, `;` and `:`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
import re

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.readlines()

data = [re.split(r'\s|;|:', row) for row in rows]
# remove the 00-00-00 bits
clean_data = [filter(lambda x: re.match(r'(0+\-+)+', x) == None, d)[:-1]
              for d in data]

mail_regex = r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+'

for d in clean_data:
    if re.match(mail_regex, d[0]) is not None:
        print 'Email: "{}" Password: "{}"'.format(d[0], d[1])
    else:
        print 'Username: "{}" Password: "{}"'.format(d[0], d[1])
```

Which produces:

```
Email: "example0@domain.tld" Password: "passw0rd"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Email: "ex.a.m-pl_e1@domain.tld" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Username: "username" Password: "password"
Username: "username" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
Username: "username" Password: "p@££w0r46&"
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, the thing with this solution is that it takes ~1.4 seconds for a file containing a mere 10k rows.

Comment: cleaning thousands of files prior to this wont work for this assignment unfortunately. But thank you for the suggestion!